# Why in React when I destructure object in import I should use 'as' but cannot use ':'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example this works:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

But this doesn’t:

```
import { BrowserRouter: Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: Because import *isn’t* the same thing as destructuring. It has a slightly different syntax.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: You also can't destructure in an import statement: `import { a: { theThingIReallyWant } } from 'library';` doesn't work. It's not the same thing. It just looks similar.

Answer (score 1):

Import has a different syntax as objects, so tools like destructuring doesn't work. If you want to learn more about what you can do, I recommend you to read [the mdn article on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

The same way, you'll find the 'as' keyword won't work with regular objects.